# Selenium in Python expected conditions works with Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

I log into a private site and then wait for a link text to appear and then open the link with browser.get().  The code below throws a timeout exception almost every time while waiting for the link text "OTD" to appear.  It is strange that it works once out of many tries.  Even stranger is that if I use a sleep timer instead of the wait for expected condition, it works, but that is not what I want to use.

Here is the html:

`<a target="_blank" href="/privateurl">OTD</a>`

And here is the code that uses chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import webbrowser

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : 'E:\\folder'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

#browser.get('private url login page')
#enter login information and submit

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "OTD"))
)

browser.get('private url')
```

I have the same code, but for the Firefox driver and it works perfectly every time.  I just need to use Chrome browser instead.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import webbrowser

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'E:\\folder')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)

browser=webdriver.Firefox(profile)

#browser.get('private url login page')
#enter login information and submit

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "OTD"))
)

browser.get('private url')
```

What am I doing wrong in the code using the chromedriver that is making it throw a timeout exception?

Comment: If you are running on the current build of Chrome `65`, if you are not running **at least** chromedriver version `2.36`, please update your chromedriver and execute your test again. Update from [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). I have been seeing a lot of issue regarding the new stable build of chrome, and older versions of the chromedriver.

Comment: That is the one I was using, but I downloaded it again through the link you provided and executed the test but still having the same problem.  I am using the current build of Chrome 65.

Comment: I edited the post to say that a sleep timer replacing the wait for expected condition works, but that is not what I want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to address :

- Finally as you are invoking `click()` on the *WebElement* so instead of the `expected_conditions` clause as `presence_of_element_located()` you should use the clause **element_to_be_clickable(locator)**.
- When you use `expected_conditions` clause as `element_to_be_clickable(locator)` the *WebElement* is returned back and you can directly invoke `click()` method on it.
- Your optimized line of code will be :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "OTD"))).click()
  ```

---

### Update A

As per your comment update you are seeing the error :

```
'element_to_be_clickable' object has no attribute 'click'
```

An alternative would be to extract the `href` attribute and invoke `get()` as follows :

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "OTD")))
attr_href = element.get_attribute("href")
driver.get(attr_href)
```

---

### Update B

As per your comment update the idea of **Selenium does interact with the element ... even though it is unable to attain visibility_of_element** is not a full proof solution as :

- The `expected_conditions` clause [`presence_of_element_located(locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) mentions :

  ```
  class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(locator)

  An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. 

  locator - used to find the element returns the WebElement once it is located.
  ```
- Where as the `expected_conditions` clause [`visibility_of_element_located(locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) mentions :

  ```
  class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(locator)

  An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. 

  locator - used to find the element returns the WebElement once it is located and visible.
  ```
- From *Selenium* perspective if an element is not **displayed** *Selenium* won't be interact with the element e.g. invoking `click()`

Comment: Thank you for this.  I am using browser.get instead of clicking because clicking the link opens the link in a new tab, which isn't what I want.  Also, this gives me an error "'element_to_be_clickable' object has no attribute 'click'"

Comment: Using visibility_of_element_located did not work with chrome or firefox as it would throw a timeout exception, but replacing it with presence_of_element_located worked in firefox and only worked the first time with chrome.  I tried it about 10 more times with chrome and it kept throwing a timeout exception.  I have found a solution by locating another element in the page.  I just think it's strange that my code works with firefox but not chrome.  Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Selenium does interact with the element in Firefox and sometimes in Chrome even though it is unable to attain visibility_of_element.  It works in Firefox when using presence_of_element but not visibility_of_element.  This is why I think the problem I was having was strange.  I will accept your answer as it was the one that has pushed me to finding a working solution.  Thank you!

Comment: That makes sense now.  Thank you!